# What is TYPE FIDELITY in the context of object serialization?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to serialize a generic class. I will store this Serialization to disk. When looking over the MSDN it said [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Binary serialization preserves type fidelity, which is useful for preserving
> the state of an object between different invocations of an
> application.

What does **Type Fidelity** mean? Will this preserve the type of object which is saved? Is there a "better" way of achieving what I want to do than serializing the object and saving it to disk?

```
public class foo<T>
{
       public T coolProperty {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20151011002917/http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=207

Comment: @DanielHilgarth good read. Thank you for the Info. will you make this an answer so i can check it as one. Again, tahnk you very much

Comment: As I only posted a link, I can't make an answer out of it as link only answers are not permitted. But you can accept Ryan's answer as it contains the essential part of this link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary serialization includes the complete state of the object, so that when you deserialize (such as in another invocation of the same application) you get an exact copy back. So yes, it will preserve the type. XML serialization includes only the public properties of the object, and is useful for passing the object data between different platforms.

Comment: Could you update this answer with a clause on what *type fidelity* is?

Answer (score 0):

**Type Fidelity:** is to ensure that information is not lost in the serialization process